# Unable to Stop-Process with Powershell

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, powershell, process

I'm spinning up an npm http-server in powershell and need to stop it before my script exists. Currently I have

```
$server = Start-Process http-server -passthru
Stop-Process -InputObject $server
```

This stops the process as far as powershell is concerned (running the stop command again fails because it is already stoped), but the window opened does not go away and the http-server continues serving requests. How do I get the http-server process to **really** stop?

---

Running as admin.
I'm mostly worried about windows 10 but this may run on other versions.
Powershell 5 is installed.

Comment: Doesn't sound like a situation that calls for `Stop-Process`. You should look for a more graceful (application native) way of stopping the http server and it's services.

Comment: Did you try to use the `-Force` switch?  `Stop-Process -InputObject $server -Force`